# Visual Studio Team Services CI build is not triggered for changes pushed by a service account

Tags: git, azure-devops

[Environment: Visual Studio Team Services, Git]

I have a VSTS build definition with triggers defined like below. In summary, I want it to be triggered whenever anything has changed under **/MyApp/Resources/** on the **develop** branch.

```
[√] Continuous integration (CI)
    Batch changes [√]
    Branch filters
        [include] develop
    Path filters
        [include] /MyApp/Resources/
```

I verified that the trigger indeed kicked off this build when I manually updated any files under the specified path (e.g. **/MyApp/Resources/Localizable.strings.localized**).

However, I found the trigger is never fired when a service account pushes changes to the same path on the same branch. I am sure its commit message doesn’t contain “ *****NO_CI***** ”.

What could be wrong here? I don’t feel the CI build trigger should behave differently for changes pushed by service account…

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: How do you make changes and check in through service account?  Based on my test, CI build wouldn't add ***NO_CI*** to the commit message, how do you do that?

Comment: @starain: Sorry I am not sure how the service account exactly does to push the changes because that part is owned by a different team. Based on my observation, this service account first creates a pull request from its private branch to our main branch, then automatically completes the PR and pushes the changes in. I'm guessing they might be using the VSTS REST API?

Comment: @starain: Oh btw, these operations done by the service account is not part of any CI build. It's probably just triggered by some other external workflow.

Comment: Is the previous build finished when the new change is pushed by service account?

Comment: @TonyBlues how do you create a CI build that could add ***NO_CI*** to the comment after build?

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT: There are no unfinished builds when the new change is pushed by the service account. However, I found after I unchecked the "Batch changes" option in the build definition. The trigger started to behave correctly. I'm not sure if this is a expected behavior...

Comment: @starain: In this particular question I'm asking here. We're not adding \*\*\*NO_CI\*\*\* during any CI build. However, I do have some other build definitions with scripts that can check-in stuff with \*\*\*NO_CI\*\*\*. You just need to include the \*\*\*NO_CI\*\*\* in your commit message when you do git commit in the script. Something like this: **git commit -m "Some description \*\*\*NO_CI\*\*\***

Comment: @TonyBlues That's why I asked you about if there is any build not finished? If you have "Batch changes" enabled, the system will wait until the build is completed and then queues another build of all changes that have not yet been built. Refer to this link for details: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/define/triggers#batch-changes. However, the issue is you said that there is no unfinished build when the new change is pushed.